# Executing Rexec using python

Tags: python, r, os.system

I use this following code to execute my Rexec:

```
os.system('"C:\\folder\\test.Rexec"')
```

It opens the file but I get an error due to a loading of a package, if I run the Rexec myself it runs without any errors because, in fact, I have the package installed.

Any help would be appreciated.

I just found out what was wrong, basically, I had 2 different folders containing R libraries and I just had to change the library path with .libPaths()

Comment: could you share the error traceback?

Comment: Is there a reason why you *single-double-quoted* the command? Doesn't `os.system('C:\\folder\\test.Rexec')` make more sense?

Comment: The reason I used double quote was just because it might contain white spaces, but that doesn't really matter because it is reading the file correctly. It gives an error concerning the package, I will share the error traceback in some minutes